# Moved Gui Builder form to another project and I can't open the Gui Builder now

Tags: codenameone

I was working on a project and I wanted to reorganize the packages, and because of the weird behaviour Codename One has when refactor/renaming GuiBuilder forms, I decided to create a new project and move those forms to the new project with the proper package organization, but now the Gui Builder won't open because it "doesn't recognize" them as Gui Builder's forms. Any fix so I dont have to create every form again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GUI builder forms are really two files:

1. A Java File
2. An XML gui file

You need to move both and keep both in the exact same hierarchy!

You can find the latter under the `res/guibuilder` hierarchy in your project.